# Can't Create A Timer On Eclipse For Java

Tags: java, eclipse, timer, arguments

I am trying to make a simple game in Java in which many things are moving. I watched a video on moving graphics that said that I need a Timer() to move something on the screen. When I try to make a timer in the form of `Timer t = new Timer(5, this);` it won't work. It tells me that there should not be any parameters for the method `Timer()`. Can I please have some help? By the way, I have only been coding java for 2 weeks, so I am very much a beginner. Here is my code:

```
   package FlappyDodgeGame;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Game extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    static int width = 1000, height = width * 9 / 12;

    public static int birdX = width * 1 / 5, birdY = height / 2, birdSize = 75;

    public static double birdVel = 0, birdVelDelta = 0.1;


    //error: The constructor Timer(int, Game) is undefined. quick fix: Remove arguments to match 'Timer()'.
    Timer timer = new Timer(5, this);

    public static void main(String args[]){
        final JFrame jframe = new JFrame("Test");
        jframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jframe.setSize(width, height);
        jframe.setResizable(false);
        jframe.setVisible(true);
        jframe.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        final GUI gui = new GUI();
        jframe.add(gui);
        jframe.addMouseListener(new MouseListener(){

            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the wrong Timer class:

```
import java.util.Timer;
```

There's another Timer class, `javax.swing.Timer`, that has a two-arg constructor.  The javadoc for this class is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html).

For a Swing application, the big advantage of using a `javax.swing.Timer` instead of a `java.util.Timer` is that when the Swing timer calls your listener, it does so on the Swing event thread, which means you can immediately call methods on all your UI objects.

Comment: Thanks, it really helped! Appreciate it!

Comment: @BenJamin If that fixed your problem, you should accept this answer by clicking the check mark next to the answer, and upvote the answer as well.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to move something on screen, you need to use a class that extends JPanel, and then implement paintComponent(Graphics g)

```
class Game extends JPanel{
    private int x_axis = 0;
    private int y_axis = 0;
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
            // do your painting here
            //e.g.
            g.drawOval(x_axis, y_axis, 200, 150);
            x_axis++;
            y_axis++;
            //
    repaint();
}
}
```

after that you can add it to your JFrame

```
frame.add(new Game());
```